# Heroku FREE DB and Dyno "power"

Tags: heroku

Can anyone have an estimate of how much data can be inserted in a 5MB database?

Also, would 1 Dyno handle a slashdot,hackernews, etc frontpage?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quiet a surprising amount... well enough to get you started thats for sure.

I use 1 dyno all the time for low traffic (like my personal website and a few xml servers, but obviously the great thing is if you start getting loads of visitors to your site and are having performance issues all it takes is one little click to add extra dynos.

Comment: Thanks. But adding dynos its very expensive. I want to be sure that I can use heroku for a reasonable price for some time.

Comment: It pays to note that dynos are billed by the second. This means that you can handle short traffic spikes very economically.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider the worker hours, not sure about what you are doing, but a lot of apps could need background process.

This service could be interesting if you are using Ruby, it scales dynos on Heroku: 
http://hirefireapp.com